# Copy formula to every 25th row, increase reference by one row

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script

I'm stuck on copying a formula in Google sheets. I want to copy a formula to a cell every 25th row, but increase the reference by just one row.

✅ example, I'd like these formulas to go into L4, L29, and L54

```
=transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(SUPIR!$N3:$AB3&" "))," "))
=transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(SUPIR!$N4:$AB4&" "))," "))
=transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(SUPIR!$N5:$AB5&" "))," "))
```

❌ what I get is...

```
=transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(SUPIR!$N3:$AB3&" "))," "))
=transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(SUPIR!$N28:$AB28&" "))," "))
=transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(SUPIR!$N53:$AB53&" "))," "))
```

I just don't know how to change the references with this formula. Any help gratefully received.

The script I've been using to set other formulas is here, but I haven't been able to get it to run successfully...

```
function setFormulas() {

  var sheet, startRow, i; 
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  startRow = 4;
  i = 4;
  while(startRow < 775) {
    sheet.getRange(startRow, 12).setFormula('=transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(SUPIR!N3:AB3&" "))," "))' + i);
    i++;
    startRow += 25;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this with Google Apps Script? if so what have you tried?

Comment: I did most of the ones I need to set 1000's of times via scripts, but I'm stuck on how to enter this formula in a script successfully. I'll edit the original question to include the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just appending i to the end of the formula.
This will create the formulas as you want them

```
function setFormulas() {
  var sheet, startRow, i; 
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  startRow = 4;
  i = 3;
  while(startRow < 775) {
    sheet.getRange(startRow, 12).setFormula('=transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(SUPIR!$N'+i+':$AB'+i+'&" "))," "))');
    i++;
    startRow += 25;
  }
}
```

Comment: Robin, cheers, it works, and its now all but complete! A year ago I didn't know how to add two cells together or make a border. Had to start to learn as my business was so disorganized. A big thank you to you, and everyone here who helps people like me with no experience in excel / sheets.. okay that's enough ;)

Comment: You're welcome and best of luck :)